# Python Clear Console Across All OSes

Tags: python, console, command

I have the following python code to clear the console on my windows computer:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

However, I would like it to work on linux as well. Is there a universal clear command that works on all operating systems, without adding a bunch of blank lines to the bottom of the console?

Comment: Yep, this works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def clear():
    print(chr(27)+'[2j')
    print('\033c')
    print('\x1bc')
```